# ffmpeg libfdk_aac output different when using tee

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use `tee` for an `ffmpeg` output using `libfdk_aac` audio and its giving me slightly different results.

To test, I am running the following 2 commands

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -t 00:01:00 -vn -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k aactest.mp4
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -t 00:01:00 -vn -map 0:a -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k -f tee "[select=\'a\']aactest_tee.mp4"
```

For `aactest.mp4`, the mediainfo output is:

```
Format                      : AAC LC
Duration                    : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 64.2 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Channel layout              : L R
Sampling rate               : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                  : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 470 KiB (98%)
```

For `aactest_tee.mp4`, the output is

```
Format                      : AAC LC
Duration                    : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode               : Variable
Bit rate                    : 61.8 kb/s
Maximum bit rate            : 64.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Channel layout              : L R
Sampling rate               : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                  : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 453 KiB (98%)
```

As can be seen, mediainfo reports variable rate for `tee` mux (which can be incorrectly detected) but the filesizes are for sure different!

Any ideas why the similar `libfdk_aac` commands are giving different outputs?